# Database of Actual Federal Holidays / Closure

Tags: language-agnostic

I am working on a coding problem and I need to check whether a past date was a federal holiday.  It is trivial and I have already pulled the historic planned holidays but there have been many federal holidays/non-working days that have been declared by Presidential Proclamation or Executive Order.  These include the day before(or) after Christmas as was done last year, the day of mourning for Former President Ford and snow emergency days that affected federal operations in DC.

So the question is, does anyone know where there is a listing of these that can be counted upon to be reasonably comprehensive.  The only things I can find are lists of the statutory holidays.

Thanks

Comment: Google Provides an xml format of holidays: https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I know of is

http://www.opm.gov/Operating_Status_Schedules/fedhol/2010.asp

You can replace the year with any year between 1997 and 2020.

Cheers
Stu

Comment: Thanks Stu-that is what I have been using but I need the other holidays or non-working days in the OPM jargon.  There are a number of algorithms to determine those and they are easily available.  I was hoping there was a list somewhere but I have not found it yet

Comment: The link in the question has been archived (it is still available as of 4/27/15).  The current link is: http://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/snow-dismissal-procedures/federal-holidays/.

Answer (score 8):

I took the time to compile the dates from the OPM website and thought I would share them here.  Hopefully this list will save someone else a bit of time in the future.  Dates are in a standard US date format (mm/dd/yyyy); they are US holidays, after all.  The list currently contains dates from 1997 through 2020.

```
01/01/1997  New Year’s Day
01/20/1997  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/17/1997  Washington’s Birthday
05/26/1997  Memorial Day
07/04/1997  Independence Day
09/01/1997  Labor Day
10/13/1997  Columbus Day
11/11/1997  Veterans Day
11/27/1997  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/1997  Christmas Day
01/01/1998  New Year’s Day
01/19/1998  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/16/1998  Washington’s Birthday
05/25/1998  Memorial Day
07/03/1998  Independence Day
09/07/1998  Labor Day
10/12/1998  Columbus Day
11/11/1998  Veterans Day
11/26/1998  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/1998  Christmas Day
01/01/1999  New Year’s Day
01/18/1999  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/15/1999  Washington’s Birthday
05/31/1999  Memorial Day
07/05/1999  Independence Day
09/06/1999  Labor Day
10/11/1999  Columbus Day
11/11/1999  Veterans Day
11/25/1999  Thanksgiving Day
12/24/1999  Christmas Day
12/31/1999  New Year’s Day
01/17/2000  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/21/2000  Washington’s Birthday
05/29/2000  Memorial Day
07/04/2000  Independence Day
09/04/2000  Labor Day
10/09/2000  Columbus Day
11/10/2000  Veterans Day
11/23/2000  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2000  Christmas Day
01/01/2001  New Year’s Day
01/15/2001  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/19/2001  Washington’s Birthday
05/28/2001  Memorial Day
07/04/2001  Independence Day
09/03/2001  Labor Day
10/08/2001  Columbus Day
11/12/2001  Veterans Day
11/22/2001  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2001  Christmas Day
01/01/2002  New Year’s Day
01/21/2002  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/18/2002  Washington’s Birthday
05/27/2002  Memorial Day
07/04/2002  Independence Day
09/02/2002  Labor Day
10/14/2002  Columbus Day
11/11/2002  Veterans Day
11/28/2002  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2002  Christmas Day
01/01/2003  New Year’s Day
01/20/2003  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/17/2003  Washington’s Birthday
05/26/2003  Memorial Day
07/04/2003  Independence Day
09/01/2003  Labor Day
10/13/2003  Columbus Day
11/11/2003  Veterans Day
11/27/2003  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2003  Christmas Day
01/01/2004  New Year's Day
01/19/2004  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/16/2004  Washington's Birthday
05/31/2004  Memorial Day
07/05/2004  Independence Day
09/06/2004  Labor Day
10/11/2004  Columbus Day
11/11/2004  Veterans Day
11/25/2004  Thanksgiving Day
12/24/2004  Christmas Day
12/31/2004  New Year’s Day
01/17/2005  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/21/2005  Washington’s Birthday
05/30/2005  Memorial Day
07/04/2005  Independence Day
09/05/2005  Labor Day
10/10/2005  Columbus Day
11/11/2005  Veterans Day
11/24/2005  Thanksgiving Day
12/26/2005  Christmas Day
01/02/2006  New Year’s Day
01/16/2006  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/20/2006  Washington’s Birthday
05/29/2006  Memorial Day
07/04/2006  Independence Day
09/04/2006  Labor Day
10/09/2006  Columbus Day
11/10/2006  Veterans Day
11/23/2006  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2006  Christmas Day
01/01/2007  New Year’s Day
01/15/2007  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/19/2007  Washington’s Birthday
05/28/2007  Memorial Day
07/04/2007  Independence Day
09/03/2007  Labor Day
10/08/2007  Columbus Day
11/12/2007  Veterans Day
11/22/2007  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2007  Christmas Day
01/01/2008  New Year’s Day
01/21/2008  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/18/2008  Washington’s Birthday
05/26/2008  Memorial Day
07/04/2008  Independence Day
09/01/2008  Labor Day
10/13/2008  Columbus Day
11/11/2008  Veterans Day
11/27/2008  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2008  Christmas Day
01/01/2009  New Year’s Day
01/19/2009  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/16/2009  Washington’s Birthday
05/25/2009  Memorial Day
07/03/2009  Independence Day
09/07/2009  Labor Day
10/12/2009  Columbus Day
11/11/2009  Veterans Day
11/26/2009  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2009  Christmas Day
01/01/2010  New Year’s Day
01/18/2010  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/15/2010  Washington’s Birthday
05/31/2010  Memorial Day
07/05/2010  Independence Day
09/06/2010  Labor Day
10/11/2010  Columbus Day
11/11/2010  Veterans Day
11/25/2010  Thanksgiving Day
12/24/2010  Christmas Day
12/31/2010  New Year’s Day
01/17/2011  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/21/2011  Washington’s Birthday
05/30/2011  Memorial Day
07/04/2011  Independence Day
09/05/2011  Labor Day
10/10/2011  Columbus Day
11/11/2011  Veterans Day
11/24/2011  Thanksgiving Day
12/26/2011  Christmas Day
01/02/2012  New Year's Day
01/16/2012  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/20/2012  Washington's Birthday
05/28/2012  Memorial Day
07/04/2012  Independence Day
09/03/2012  Labor Day
10/08/2012  Columbus Day
11/12/2012  Veterans Day
11/22/2012  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2012  Christmas Day
01/01/2013  New Year’s Day
01/21/2013  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/18/2013  Washington’s Birthday
05/27/2013  Memorial Day
07/04/2013  Independence Day
09/02/2013  Labor Day
10/14/2013  Columbus Day
11/11/2013  Veterans Day
11/28/2013  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2013  Christmas Day
01/01/2014  New Year’s Day
01/20/2014  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/17/2014  Washington’s Birthday
05/26/2014  Memorial Day
07/04/2014  Independence Day
09/01/2014  Labor Day
10/13/2014  Columbus Day
11/11/2014  Veterans Day
11/27/2014  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2014  Christmas Day
01/01/2015  New Year’s Day
01/19/2015  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/16/2015  Washington’s Birthday
05/25/2015  Memorial Day
07/03/2015  Independence Day
09/07/2015  Labor Day
10/12/2015  Columbus Day
11/11/2015  Veterans Day
11/26/2015  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2015  Christmas Day
01/01/2016  New Year’s Day
01/18/2016  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/15/2016  Washington’s Birthday
05/30/2016  Memorial Day
07/04/2016  Independence Day
09/05/2016  Labor Day
10/10/2016  Columbus Day
11/11/2016  Veterans Day
11/24/2016  Thanksgiving Day
12/26/2016  Christmas Day
01/02/2017  New Year’s Day
01/16/2017  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/20/2017  Washington’s Birthday
05/29/2017  Memorial Day
07/04/2017  Independence Day
09/04/2017  Labor Day
10/09/2017  Columbus Day
11/10/2017  Veterans Day
11/23/2017  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2017  Christmas Day
01/01/2018  New Year’s Day
01/15/2018  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/19/2018  Washington’s Birthday
05/28/2018  Memorial Day
07/04/2018  Independence Day
09/03/2018  Labor Day
10/08/2018  Columbus Day
11/12/2018  Veterans Day
11/22/2018  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2018  Christmas Day
01/01/2019  New Year’s Day
01/21/2019  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/18/2019  Washington’s Birthday
05/27/2019  Memorial Day
07/04/2019  Independence Day
09/02/2019  Labor Day
10/14/2019  Columbus Day
11/11/2019  Veterans Day
11/28/2019  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2019  Christmas Day
01/01/2020  New Year’s Day
01/20/2020  Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.
02/17/2020  Washington’s Birthday
05/25/2020  Memorial Day
07/03/2020  Independence Day
09/07/2020  Labor Day
10/12/2020  Columbus Day
11/11/2020  Veterans Day
11/26/2020  Thanksgiving Day
12/25/2020  Christmas Day
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I had the same need and your list will be REALLY helpful to me.  Thanks.